# Read text of a open window in a linux shell

Tags: shell, window, wmctrl

i have a little script that runs commands depending on the title of opened windows. I read that titles using

```
wmctrl -l
```

Some of the window titles are very general. Can i read the window text using the linux shell? It seems wmtcrl can't do this. Is there any other tool?

Comment: Could you give us an example of what you mean by `very general`? I'm looking at my own out of curiosity and everything has some specificity: `0x03200028  0 2930   kahnbox Read text of a open window in a linux shell - Unix & Linux Stack Exchange - Mozilla Firefox`, `0x06400007  0 16361  kahnbox Screenshot from 2020-06-15 10-04-01.png` for examples (you can pull their PIDs with `-p`). This older article has some more depth for what you're trying to do: https://www.linuxjournal.com/magazine/hack-and-automate-your-desktop-wmctrl

Comment: The title is something like "notification". Nothing that i can use to choose the next command.  the pid is changed every time i start the application.